# Renaming tuple column name in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am new to python and pandas. I have attached a picture of a pandas dataframe,
[image: Pic]
I need to know how I can fetch data from the last column and how to rename the last column.

Comment: I'd up vote this question if you provided actual data instead of a picture of data.

Answer (score 12):

You can use:

```
df = df.rename(columns = {df.columns[-1] : 'newname'})
```

Or:

```
df.columns = df.columns[:-1].tolist() + ['new_name']
```

It seems solution:

```
df.columns.values[-1] = 'newname'
```

is buggy. Because after rename pandas functions return weird errors.

For fetch data from last column is possible use select by position by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
s = df.iloc[:,-1]
```

And after rename:

```
s1 = df['newname']
print (s1)
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'R':[7,8,9],
                   'T':[1,3,5],
                   'E':[5,3,6],
                   ('Z', 'a'):[7,4,3]})

print (df)
   E  T  R  (Z, a)
0  5  1  7       7
1  3  3  8       4
2  6  5  9       3

s = df.iloc[:,-1]
print (s)
0    7
1    4
2    3
Name: (Z, a), dtype: int64
```

---

```
df.columns = df.columns[:-1].tolist() + ['new_name']
print (df)
   E  T  R  new_name
0  5  1  7         7
1  3  3  8         4
2  6  5  9         3
```

---

```
df = df.rename(columns = {('Z', 'a') : 'newname'})
print (df)
   E  T  R  newname
0  5  1  7        7
1  3  3  8        4
2  6  5  9        3
```

```
s = df['newname']
print (s)
0    7
1    4
2    3
Name: newname, dtype: int64
```

```
df.columns.values[-1] = 'newname'
s = df['newname']
print (s)
>KeyError: 'newname'
```

Comment: Good, just making sure you see it :-).  I always want you to vote your conscience.  And you do.  I hope you know I totally respect that.  In this case, I like the solution as it represents how I think.  I'll leave it as is.  And hopefully, we see more questions soon.

Answer (score 5):

> fetch data from the last column

Retrieving the last column using `df.iloc[:,-1]` as suggested by other answers works fine only when it is indeed the last column.

However, using absolute column positions like `-1` is not a stable solution, i.e. if you add some other column, your code will break.

**A stable, generic approach**

First of all, make sure all your column names are strings:

```
# rename columns
df.columns = [str(s) for s in df.columns]
# access column by name
df['(vehicle_id, reservation_count)']
```

> rename the last column

It is preferable to have similar column names for all columns, without brackets in them - make your code more readable and your dataset easier to use:

```
# access column by name
df['vehicle_id_reservation_count`]
```

This is a straight forward conversion on all columns that are named by a tuple:

```
# rename columns
def rename(col):
    if isinstance(col, tuple):
        col = '_'.join(str(c) for c in col)
    return col
df.columns = map(rename, df.columns)
```

Comment: If the tuple is a mix of string and float, use this instead: "col = '{}_{}'.format(col[0], col[1])"

Comment: @Superpronker adopted your hint for tuples of any length

Answer (score 1):

You can drop the last column and reassign it with a different name.
This isn't technically renaming the column.  However, I think its intuitive.

Using @jezrael's setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'R':[7,8,9],
                   'T':[1,3,5],
                   'E':[5,3,6],
                   ('Z', 'a'):[7,4,3]})

print(df)

   R  T  E  (Z, a)
0  7  1  5       7
1  8  3  3       4
2  9  5  6       3
```

> How can I fetch the last column?

You can use `iloc`

```
df.iloc[:, -1]

0    5
1    3
2    6
Name: c, dtype: int64
```

You can rename the column after you've extracted it

```
df.iloc[:, -1].rename('newcolumn')

0    5
1    3
2    6
Name: newcolumn, dtype: int64
```

In order to rename it within the dataframe, you can do a great number of ways.  To continue with the theme that I've started, namely, fetching the column, then renaming it:

***option 1***
start by dropping the last column with `iloc[:, :-1]`
use `join` to add the renamed column referenced above

```
df.iloc[:, :-1].join(df.iloc[:, -1].rename('newcolumn'))

   R  T  E  newname
0  7  1  5        7
1  8  3  3        4
2  9  5  6        3
```

***option 2***
Or we can use `assign` to put it back and save the `rename`

```
df.iloc[:, :-1].assign(newname=df.iloc[:, -1])

   R  T  E  newname
0  7  1  5        7
1  8  3  3        4
2  9  5  6        3
```

Answer (score 0):

For changeing the column name

```
columns=df.columns.values
columns[-1]="Column name"
```

For fetch data from dataframe

You can use loc,iloc and ix methods.

loc is for fetch value using label
iloc is for fetch value using indexing
ix can fetch data with both using index and label

Learn about loc and iloc
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#indexing-selection

Learn more about indexing and selecting data

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html

Comment: Hmmm, I test your solution and it return weird keyerror - see my answer bottom. How does it work for you? `df = pd.DataFrame({'R':[7,8,9],
                   'T':[1,3,5],
                   'E':[5,3,6],
                   ('Z', 'a'):[7,4,3]})

print (df)` and `df.columns.values[-1] = 'newname'`
`s = df['newname']`
`print (s)` ?

Comment: I thought you want to change column name for display purpose only. Sorry for misunderstanding. @jezrael has gave the proper solution.