# Python - Renaming tuple column headers

Tags: python, pandas

I have checked out:

[Renaming tuple column name in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43290051/renaming-tuple-column-name-in-dataframe)

None of the responses seem to work.

I have a dataframe that has tuples as column headers:

```
list(dfA)

[('Total', 'Book'),
 ('Total', 'Book Chapter'),
 ('Total', 'Book edited'),
 ('Total', 'Conference Proceeding_Abstract'),
 ('Total', 'Consultancy Report'),
 ('Total', 'Journal Article'),
 ('Total', 'Manual / Guide'),
 ('Total', 'Manual/Guide'),
 ('Total', 'Monograph'),
 ('Total', 'Other'),
 ('Total', 'Policy briefing_report'),
 ('Total', 'Scholarly edition'),
 ('Total', 'Systematic review'),
 ('Total', 'Technical Report'),
 ('Total', 'Technical Standard'),
 ('Total', 'Thesis'),
 ('Total', 'Working Paper')]
```

I have tried several ways of renaming them, but it wont work. I should mention that the columns may change, but this is the maximum amount that there will be (hence why I am not using location)

This code I have tried is:

```
dfA.rename(columns = {('Total', 'Book') : 'Book'})
dfA = dfA.rename(columns = {('Total', 'Book') : 'Book'})
dfA.rename(columns={'('Total', 'Book')':"Book"})
```

I have also tried converting them to Strings like so:

```
dfA.columns = [str(s) for s in dfA.columns]
```

Yet, it sill wont change anything. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need if need second value of tuples `list comprehension`:

```
dfA.columns = [x[1] for x in dfA.columns]
```

Comment: Wow that was quick. I just stepped away from my desk for a few minutes, as soon as I'm back I'll give it a go :) thank you

Comment: Perfect. The first one didnt work as apparently its a multi index, but the second one worked perfectly. Thank you Jezrael!